# cellForRowAtIndexPath not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm working on an app on xCode 5. I'm using a `UIViewController` which contains a `UIImageView` for the background Image , also I have two Views (at the top and bottom) and a `UITableView` in between them.

I am using AutoLayout (which I don't want to change). The problem is that the *tabelcells* are not being displayed.

I debugged it with break points I found out that the the break-point at the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is never hit but the break points at `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` (I'm returning value '1' in this) are.

Here is the View did Load Method :

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
  [super viewDidLoad];

self.imgViewSurveyItem=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-106, -238,-874, -1262)];
self.tblViewSurveyItem =[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18, 82, 733, 854)];
self.tblViewSurveyItem.dataSource=self;
self.tblViewSurveyItem.delegate=self;
[self.tblViewSurveyItem reload];
}
```

these are the initialisations of the two views:

```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tblViewSurveyItem;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imgViewSurveyItem;
```

Here is the NumberofRowinSection

```
  -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
         return [self.QuestionData count];
   }
```

Please provide some solution without disabling AutoLayout.

Here is cellOfForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    APMBasicSurveyItemTableeViewCell *cell = [self.tblViewSurveyItem dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:APMSurveyItemBasicCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    APMQuestion * Question= [self.QuestionData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblQuestionDetail.text= Question.Detail;
    return cell;
```

Comment: Please show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Also, have you created the tableView in IB? If so, why are you allocating a new one?  If not, where do you add the new tableView to your view?

Comment: So, is numberOfRowsInSection returning a non-zero number?

Comment: Yes it is Because there is a proto type cell with couple of records binded with it

Comment: You know, the code above still has the painfully obvious flaw of setting the dataSource and delegete pointers before it sets the table view pointer.  There's no point in even looking at your problem until that is fixed.  (And by now we can't really trust anything you say, so you might as well give up.)

Comment: @HotLicks for your information I was using IBOutlet and  initialization both to link table tableView and that is the reason my breakpoints (except the one at cellforrowatindexpath) was hitting even with some code error. I'm not using IBoutlets now but just the initialization and hence I have updated the code.

Comment: But the painfully obvious bug is still there.

Comment: @HotLicks which Bug are you talking about

Comment: I got its an editting Error

Comment: As I said, by now we can't really trust anything you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you've missed it in my very long comment below:
Either remove the alloc-init methods (since they are outlets created in Interface Builder),
Or change it to:

```
self.imgViewSurveyItem = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-106, -238,-874, -1262)];
self.tblViewSurveyItem = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18, 82, 733, 854)];
self.tblViewSurveyItem.dataSource=self;
self.tblViewSurveyItem.delegate=self;
[self.view addSubview: self.imgViewSurveyItem];
[self.view addSubview: self.tblViewSurveyItem]
```

Comment: Did it still the same issue

Comment: If you deleted the outlet connection, please also delete the IBOutlet of your properties.

Comment: Did it and replaced it with
      property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tblViewSurveyItem;
      property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imgViewSurveyItem;

Comment: Is it possible to have a tableview inside UIViewController with Dynamic PrototypeCell and Autollayout eabled ?

Comment: Sure. but I don't get why the data source method doesn't being called..... Are you sure you write the cellForRowAtIndexPath correctly? And are you sure you set the viewController to be the correct one? Would you mind share more code from your program, to see what exactly is going on?

Comment: Ok I'll edit the code in the question as soon as possibly, Its really important for me so please help me with this

Comment: I have added the cellforRowAtIndexPath code I'll add the rest tomorrow.

Comment: Well I did everything again and it worked. Thanx I think i messed up somewhere while initializing of delegates and  datasource.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the delegate and data source properties of the tank view and then creating the table view.

You need to add the delegate and data source AFTER creating it.

Comment: No it didn't worked its still the same however I have updated your suggestion

Comment: @SaurabhSingh - Fogmeister clearly is correct.  You above source sets dataSource and delegate before setting the pointer to the table view.  So those settings are vanishing into thin air.  Of course, you claim that numberOfRowsInSection is getting called, which means that **you are not showing us the real code**.  This is a big no-no.

Comment: @HotLicks - I have added these two lines
          self.imgViewSurveyItem=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-106, -238,-874, -1262)];
          self.tblViewSurveyItem =[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18, 82, 733, 854)];

after few attempts initialy it didnt existed. But yes later even after code changes the result remained unchanged.And for your information I have successfully performed the same functionality   in UITableViewController and now when I trying to do it in UIViewController it showing the mentioned.

Comment: @OK I'm Editting above question Code. you can have alook at that

Comment: I noticed as well that you have the table view as an outlet. Remove the code `self.tblView = blah`. Your table is being created by the nib so you don't need to create it in code.

Comment: @Fogmeister : Imagine I have deleted the outlet connections and DidLoad content can you please tell me the steps to initialize the DataSource and Delegate, I think this is the point where I'm going Wrong

Comment: Can you put the entire class code into gist and put a link to it. Without seeing it all its very difficult to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way...

```
self.imgViewSurveyItem=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-106, -238,-874, -1262)];
self.tblViewSurveyItem =[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18, 82, 733, 854)];

self.tblViewSurveyItem.dataSource=self;
self.tblViewSurveyItem.delegate=self;
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: No it didn't worked its still the same however I have updated your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Are you conforms to both UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource?

Also, try to call `[self.tblViewSurveyItem reloadData]` manually and see if it gets called.

Comment: still the same. moreover i noticed that although i have initialized the delegate and the data source of the table view (as mentioned above) I am unable to see them in the connection inspector present in the utility Area when I select the table view in my story board. Am I missing something in the initialization?

Comment: When you set the delegate and data source programatically you won't see a connection.  When I think about it, I don't think you should alloc-init outlets you set in Interface Builder.  I think you should do one of the following: either delete the alloc-init of the table view, or after alloc-init add [self.view addSubview: self.tblViewSurvyeyItem].

Comment: As a follow up to my comment above- I think that what is happening is you alloc-init a table view, but doesn't actually adding it to the current view. So cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't being called, since it doesn't need to because the table view is not actually visible on the screen. I think that if you create table view in Interface Builder, and then alloc-init it, you actually 'deleting' the one created in Interface Builder and you create a new one, which, again, should be added to the current view.

Comment: It does provide an answer, plus an explenation. It's a follow up to his comment of my post. Have you even read it before posting?

Comment: @AMI289 I have the same feeling regarding the Issue because I have successfully performed the same proceedure in TableViewController and it worked but with VieewController it didnt. But I tried after deleting the current outlet connection in-spite of that I'm using simple property type variables of UITableView and UIImageView type. but its the same. I think I'm really missing something

Comment: Have you tried what I've suggested, to add them to as a subviews to your current view? [self.view addSubview: self.tblViewSurveyItem] and [self.view addSubview: self.imgViewSurveyItem]

Comment: @AMI289 yes,imagine I have deleted the outlet connections and cleared didViewload content can u please provide with the appropraite DidViewLoad code

Comment: Look at my other answer above. It will be more clear there than in a comment.